# Не удаляется элемент в JS

Tags: javascript

Это шаблон регистрации для практики. При клике на sign in или sign up появляется стрелка, которая должна была удалиться при клике на document. При клике на button стрелка перемещается на кликнутый button. При изменении масштаба окна, стрелка перемещается, как ее завиксировать по центру под тегом button. И как сделать так чтобы стрелка перемещалась с анимацией.

```js
let signInBtn = document.querySelector("#sign_in");
let signUpBtn = document.querySelector("#sign_up");
let loginWrapper = document.querySelector(".login");
let registWrapper = document.querySelector(".registration");
let btns = document.querySelector(".btns");
btns.classList.remove("pseudo");

signInBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loginWrapper.style.display = "block";
  btns.classList.add("pseudo");

  btns.classList.remove("active");

  // btns.className = 'pseudo'
});
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target !== signInBtn && loginWrapper !== e.target.closest(".login")) {
    loginWrapper.style.display = "none";
    btns.classList.add("pseudo");
  }
  if (
    e.target !== signUpBtn &&
    registWrapper !== e.target.closest(".registration")
  ) {
    registWrapper.style.display = "none";
    btns.classList.add("pseudo");
  }

});

signUpBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  registWrapper.style.display = "block";
  btns.classList.add("pseudo");

  btns.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,800&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  /* background-image: url(); */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background: bisque;
}

.container {
  width: 35%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 60px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: transparent;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.login {
  display: none;
  /* padding: 50px; */
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.registration {
  display: none;
  /* padding: 50px; */
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btns {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  /* transition: 1s; */
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.cancel {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.cancel {}

input {
  font-family: 'Moserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

#sign_in {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

#sign_up {
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: black;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.btns.pseudo::before {
  content: "";
  /* width: 15px;
    height: 15px; */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  position: absolute;
  /* transform: rotate(45deg); */
  top: 62px;
  left: 95px;
  /* color: beige;
    background-color: aqua; */
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}


/* .btns.pseudo::after{
    content: "";
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 102.5px;
    background-color: aqua;

} */

.btns.pseudo.active::before {
  left: 280px;
}

.btns.pseudo.active::after {
  left: 277.5px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btns pseudo active">
    <div class="signinc">
      <button id="sign_in">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <div class="signupc">
      <button id="sign_up">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="registration">
    <input type="text" id="register_login" placeholder="type your login">
    <input type="text" id="register_password" placeholder="type your password">
    <input type="text" id="register_confirm" placeholder="repeat your password">
    <button class="save">Cancel</button>
    <button class="cancel">Open</button>
  </div>

  <div class="login">
    <input type="text" id="login_nickname" placeholder="type your login">
    <input type="text" id="login_password" placeholder="type your password">
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="open">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>
```